# Does a set moon sky equal a new moon sky?

Tags: star, the-moon, photography, moon-phases

I am planning some astrophotography. And comparing two times.

On one night I plan a midnight shoot when a waning crescent moon rises at 1am. This is 1 week ahead of the new moon.

The other night would be on a new moon.

Would the darkness of the sky be expected to be any different? I ask because a lot of articles I read about stargazing and astrophotography say the phases of the moon are important, but never mention the setting and rising of the moon as an important factor.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1968/lunar-twilight-and-sixth-magnitude-stars may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the moon has set, the sky is dark. There is a little "lunar twilight", but this is pretty insignificant. Once the moon has set you don't need to worry about the moon. The sky will be dark at midnight.